# Get numbers that immediately follow @ symbol in string

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match-all, text-extraction

Imagine I have a textarea with the following value.

```
@3115
Hello this is a test post.

@115
Test quote
```

I'm trying to find a way in PHP using regex that will get the **numeric value** that comes after the '@' symbol even if there's multiple symbols.

I imagine storing the values that are returned from the regex into an array is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Martin
yes it will always be the number after the @ symbol

Comment: Actually can you clarify if you want *all* the values or just the first? I assumed you wanted all of them, but rereading your post it's ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Using a `preg_match_all` function as an example, but the function doesn't matter, the Regex within does:*)

```
  $inputString = "@3115
        Hello this is a test post.
        @115
       Test quote";
  preg_match_all("/@(\d+)/",$inputString,$output);
  //$output[1] = "3115";      
  //$output[2] = "115";
```

This will find a `@` character, and then find `\d` which is any numerical value, and then `+` means to catch [the numerical value] one or more times. the `()` makes this a **capture group** so will only return the number found and not the `@` preceeding it.

Comment: This is misleading.  `preg_match()` will not make multiple matches.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$str = <<<EOF
@3115
Hello this is a test post.

@115
Test quote
EOF;

preg_match_all('/@(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // Returns an array like ['3115', '115']
```

The `preg_match_all` function gets all the occurrences of the regex in the input string and returns the capture group.

#### Regex breakdown

`/@(\d+)/`

- `@` matches the character literally.
- `(` starts a capture group.
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]).
- `+` means the digit can be repeated one or more times.
- `)` ends the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Match the `@`, forget it with `\K`, then match one or more digits as the fullstring match.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0mT3Z))

```
$str = <<<TEXT
@3115
Hello this is a test post.

@115
Test quote
TEXT;

preg_match_all('/@\K\d+/', $str, $matches);
var_export($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '3115',
  1 => '115',
)
```